# Excel VBA retrieve and paste values of column A where column B equal specific value

Tags: excel, vba

Please see below image example.

Column A and B are static. cell E2 (yellow) is actually a drop down list (or equal to cell which is actually a drop down list).

I need a macro (ideally a sheet change type rather than click button module) that when e2  changes/picked it pastes in cell H2 all the values from column A where column B = e2 (picked value).

[image]

in this case, e2 = 7. there are four records in column A where column B=7 (blue highlight) and I want them pasted in H2 (grey column - desired result).

can someone help with a rough guide to do this and the type of functions I should use and I should be able to write it. Thanks

Comment: Please show your attempt. SO is not a place where you can just throw your tasks and expect somebody to do your work. As a minimum, you need to show your own attempt and explain what iw wrong with it.

Comment: What about `XLookup()`?

Comment: For the *Worksheet Change* event to work, `E2` can't be a formula i.e. a dropdown (a value) is the way to go. You have to keep in mind that you need to clear the previous results. If the results are only values, you can make it efficient by introducing arrays. If you need the formatting as well, the most efficient way would be using `Advanced Filter` which would require the headers `Column A` and `Column B` e.g. in cells `D1` and `E1` respectively. Let us know which version you would like to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. It uses the `Change` event and tests for the cell E2. The code defines the input range automatically. Copy it to the worksheet's code window.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E2")) Is Nothing Then
  lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  Range(Cells(2, 8), Cells(lastrow, 8)).Delete
  pointer = 2
  For i = 2 To lastrow
    If Target = Cells(i, "B") Then
      Cells(pointer, 8) = Cells(i, "A")
      pointer = pointer + 1
    End If
  Next i
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Black cat. The exact solution. Nothing less.

Answer (score 1):

In cell H2 you can use the formula:

```
=FILTER(A2:A1000,B2:B1000=E2)
```

This will give the desired result without the need for vba.

What the function does is look up and compare the cells in B to E2 and the result is the values from column A.

Comment: Note that this works only in 365, not in older versions of Excel

Answer (score 0):

### A Worksheet Change: Lookup Matches Using DropDown

[image]

**Main - Sheet Module e.g. `Sheet1`**

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const TGT_CELL As String = "E2"
    Const DST_CELL As String = "H2"
    Const LOOKUP_COLUMN As Long = 2
    Const RETURN_COLUMN As Long = 1
    
    Dim tcell As Range: Set tcell = Intersect(Me.Range(TGT_CELL), Target)
    If tcell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim dr As Long ' number of resulting rows
    
    Dim tVal As Variant: tVal = tcell.Value
    If IsError(tVal) Then GoTo WriteResult
    If Len(tVal) = 0 Then GoTo WriteResult
    
    Dim srg As Range, rCount As Long, cCount As Long
    
    With Me.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        rCount = .Rows.Count - 1
        If rCount < 1 Then GoTo WriteResult
        cCount = .Columns.Count
        If cCount < Application.Max(LOOKUP_COLUMN, RETURN_COLUMN) Then
            GoTo WriteResult
        End If
        Set srg = .Resize(rCount).Offset(1)
    End With
    
    Dim rData() As Variant: rData = GetRange(srg.Columns(RETURN_COLUMN))
    
    Dim lData() As Variant: lData = GetRange(srg.Columns(LOOKUP_COLUMN))
    lData = Application.Match(lData, Array(tVal), 0)
    
    Dim lVal As Variant, rVal As Variant, sr As Long
    
    For sr = 1 To rCount
        If IsNumeric(lData(sr, 1)) Then
            dr = dr + 1
            rData(dr, 1) = rData(sr, 1) ' write to the top
        End If
    Next sr
        
WriteResult:
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        With Me.Range(DST_CELL)
            ' Write values.
            If dr > 0 Then .Resize(dr).Value = rData
            ' Clear (below).
            .Resize(Me.Rows.Count - .Row - dr + 1).Offset(dr).Clear
        End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
End Sub
```

**Help - Standard Module e.g. `Module1` or same as `Main`**

```vb
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the values of a range in a 2D one-based array.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetRange(ByVal rg As Range) As Variant
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Get Range"
    
    If rg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The range is 'Nothing'.", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    Dim Data() As Variant
    
    If rg.Cells.CountLarge = 1 Then
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = rg.Value
    Else
        Data = rg.Value
    End If
    
    GetRange = Data
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Worksheets("Sheetx").Range("E2")) Is Nothing Then 'where equal to drop down value
  lastrow = Worksheets("Sheetx").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'finding last row of output col
  Debug.Print lastrow ' print last row
  Worksheets("Sheetx").Range(Cells(2, 9), Cells(lastrow, 9)).Delete 'desired result area clear
  pointer = 2
  For i = 2 To lastrow 'start from row 2 to last row
    If Target = Worksheets("Sheetx").Cells(i, "B") Then ' searching column B
      Worksheets("Sheetx").Cells(pointer, 9) = Worksheets("Sheetx").Cells(i, "A") ' retrieving col A result
      pointer = pointer + 1 'go to next row
    End If
  Next i
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is the final solution I went with based off Black Cats, now with comments